# What's the correct way to namespace service objects in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to create multiple classes each of which are in the same namespace and I'd like them to be in different files.

i.e.

`# app/services/core_metatags`

```
module Metatags::CoreMetatags
  #...
end
```

and `# app/services/twitter_card`

```
module Metatags::TwitterCard
  #...
end
```

and `# app/services/facebook_open_graph`

```
module Metatags::FacebookOpenGraph
  #...
end
```

I'd like each of these modules to be put into different files. However when I try doing this I get the following error:

```
Unable to autoload constant TwitterCard, expected 
/Users/peter/project/app/services/twitter_card.rb to define it
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it incorrect to namespace this way? Or is it a directory naming problem...?

Comment: You need to put them in app/services/metatags folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a directory for the namespace, so that:

- `Metatags::CoreMetatags` goes in `app/services/metatags/core_metatags.rb`.
- `Metatags::TwitterCard` goes in `app/services/metatags/twitter_card.rb`.
- `Metatags::FacebookOpenGraph` goes in `app/services/metatags/facebook_open_graph.rb`.

Comment: whammo. Worked like a charm - ty